# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in taxonomy_field_formatter_view()

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms, media, files

My Drupal installation has some warnings, I tried several patches, but none of them works for me. These are the warning messages:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in taxonomy_field_formatter_prepare_view() (line 1677 of modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in taxonomy_field_formatter_view() (line 1600 of modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).

It looks like I get those warnings randomly, I can't find a specific handling.

I think I get this message when I create/edit a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2062721#comment-8906361), this warning can be eliminated by editing the field on each file type which is having a field and unchecking *Override in WYSIWYG* (at `/admin/structure/file-types`). This happens because term reference doesn't support overridable in the WYSIWYG.

This issue at Drupal.org: [#2062721: Add a white list of file fields that can be overwritten when the file is added in the wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/node/2062721), aiming to solve that issue. At time of writing, there is still some patch which is in *Needs review* status.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is using `hook_field_formatter_prepare_view`, it checks if the term which has been passed to it exists or not. So please check the term which are going through it, if it exists or not.